# finding closest value in another list

Tags: java

Please let me know if the question is not clear. I can provide more info. I have following musical notes in ArrayList

```
ArrayList<String> notesList = new ArrayList<>();
notesList.add("A");    //0
notesList.add("A#");    //1
notesList.add("B");     //2
notesList.add("C");     //3
notesList.add("C#");    //4
notesList.add("D");     //5
notesList.add("D#");    //6
notesList.add("E");     //7
notesList.add("F");     //8
notesList.add("F#");    //9
notesList.add("G");     //10
notesList.add("G#");    //11
```

I have two sub lists, one for ascending and one for descending. both of them contain notes which are part of notesList.

```
ArrayList<String> ascendList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> descendList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Ex:

```
ascendList = C, D, E, F#, G        //indices in notesList = 3,5,7,9,10
descendList = A, C#, E, F, G, G#   // indices in notesList = 0,4,7,8,10,11
```

I need to generate patterns by going through ascending list and then descending an vice versa.
example:

> D, E (from Ascending list), E, C# (from Descending list) C,D,E,F#
>
> (Ascend), F,E,C#,A (Descend)
>
> F E C# (Descend), D, E (Ascend)

There is a condition for doing this. When I want to connect descending pattern at end of ascending pattern, I need to find the next note equal to or below the last ascending note, but in the descending list.

Ex: if F# is the last note in one of the pattern of ascending type, F should be the first note in descending pattern. If E is the last note in ascending pattern, again E is the first note in descending pattern since E is present in both ascend and descend. Similarly when I generate ascending pattern at the end of descending pattern, I need to find next note equal to or higher the last descending note.

I could not figure out how to do this.
One method I tried was to go for indices for both ascending and descending corresponding to `notesList` and then thought of mapping and then using `map.higherKey`, `map.lowerKey`, etc methods. But unable to proceed because I could not really map them.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: Coding is not done yet. But what I planned was: first we know the last note from where connection has to be made to the other list. With this position, I can know the position in notesList (Ex: position of note E = 7 in notesList). Now see if this exists in other list. If not either increment or decrement the index (depending on increasing type of decreasing type) and see if match is found. I am thinking there may be better/simple method using maps so that coding can be reduced.

Answer (score 1):

```
enum Note {
    C, C_, D, D_, E, F, F_, G, G_, A, A_, B;

    public Note above() {
        return ordinal() != values().length - 1
                ? Note.values()[ordinal() + 1]
                : Note.values()[0];
    }

    public Note below() {
        return ordinal() > 0
                ? Note.values()[ordinal() - 1]
                : Note.values()[Note.values().length - 1];
    }
}

interface Scale {
    ListIterator<Note> joinAfter(Note note);
}

Scale ascending = new Scale() {
    List<Note> notes = asList(C, D, E, F_, G);

    @Override
    public ListIterator<Note> joinAfter(Note note) {
        return notes.listIterator(notes.contains(note)? notes.indexOf(note) : notes.indexOf(note.above()));
    }
};

Scale descending = new Scale() {
    List<Note> notes = asList(A, C_, E, F, G, G_);

    @Override
    public ListIterator<Note> joinAfter(Note note) {
        return notes.listIterator(notes.contains(note)? notes.indexOf(note) : notes.indexOf(note.below()));
    }
};
```

I'd recomend to add your own `Iterator` wrapper which will call previous for next in descendingScale (if you don't want for some reason reverse notes there) and more importantly allow you to infinitely loop through scales.

If this is just a school asignment you better stick with the numbers and don't mess with the lists of strings untill you need to print things out. Btw array will be a better choice here.

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach. For ascending and descending create arrays of Ints (or Booleans) of the same size as your notesList. A value of 1 means that the note is in the list, a value of 0 means it is not. Basically you use the acceding/descending structures to index into noteList. Something like:

```
int index = 3;
if (1 == acending[index]) {
    note = noteList[index];
}
```

Create methods to move the index up and down the ascending and descending lists looking for the next valid (non-zero) entry. When you switch from ascending to descending you use the same index on the descending list. If you're on a valid note then use it, is not, search down for the next valid one.

Lots of variations are possible. You can create object called AscendingScale and DescendingScale that encapsulate the list and move methods.